# How do you compare an element in a string with "-"?

Tags: c#, .net, string, char

I have an if statement where the condition is `if (String.Equals(str[0], "-"))`
and the condition is never met even when it should be. So I believe I am misunderstanding how the .Equals() method works. I have also tried `Char.Equals(str[0], "-")`, However the condition is still never met. I am using C#. Please help me understand what is causing this issue. Thanks.

Comment: Are you wanting to test the first character of the string is a -?

Comment: This is ridiculously vague. What's the value of `str`? Post some code, how are we supposed to help without it

Comment: Can you add a working example, there is no reason it should not work, have a look: https://rextester.com/GZOD7227

Comment: If `str` is a string, then `str[0]` is a char (so you need `'-'`).

Comment: Can you share the example string?

Comment: try this `str[0].Equals('-')`

Comment: You most likely have a special encoding you're using to look for that character. Find the char code for the dash you're looking for (cast the char as an int) and look for that instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way

```
using System;
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var str = "-";
        Console.WriteLine(str[0].Equals('-'));
    }
}
```

Comment: you forgot "the condition is never met even when it should be"

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var str = "-+=";
if(str[0].Equals('-'))
{
    MessageBox.Show("");
}
```